# Looking for specific page url in Google

Tags: c#, google-search-api

I want to do get specific page url from google but where is problem? Let me explain.
I am searching in google ( Google.Api.Search ) for specific keyword for example "google api"

```
var client = new GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com");
var results = client.Search("google api", 100);
foreach (var webResult in results)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", webResult.Title, webResult.Url, webResult.Content);
    listBox1.Items.Add(webResult.ToString ());
}
```

Ok, it works fine but now is the problem because **I want to open specific page**

I am looking for "google api" but I want to open this website Google API Tutorial - W3Schools
www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp which one is on second page but also it can be on 3-4 page.

How Can I search specific address in google?

Comment: Are you asking how to examine the webResult for a specific url that you know in advance, or are you asking how to "open" a page?

Comment: webResult for a specific url

Comment: if (webResult.Url.StartsWith("some_domain")) { doSomething(); }

Comment: will search through the pages until find this url? Even it be on 7 page?